# Q.js map in parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, q, async.js

I need to make `map` with async functions like `async.map` [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async).
Is there a way to make it with [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)?

Comment: look at https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promise-for-array-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the power of Q combined with the inherent power of Array…

```
return Q.all(values.map(function (value) {
    return getPromise(value);
}));
```

This will return a promise for an array of results.